# ffmpeg libvpx-vp9 change clock rate

Tags: ffmpeg, vp9

I have some problems with live vp9 encode via ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -protocol_whitelist file,crypto,udp,rtp -i /tmp/sdp_files/33228ae0-ed0c-4935-9da4-c55ae6a177b8.sdp -r 30 -an -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -quality realtime -threads 16 -tune 1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -speed 16 -f webm udp://232.3.4.5:7540
```

Input stream

```
Input #0, sdp, from '/tmp/sdp_files/33228ae0-ed0c-4935-9da4-c55ae6a177b8.sdp':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.084000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0, 31, 1/90000: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(progressive, left), 640x480, 0/1, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
```

Output stream

```
Output #0, webm, to 'udp://232.3.4.5:7540':
  Metadata:
    title           : -
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/1000: Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), 1 reference frame, yuv420p(left), 640x480, 0/1, q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
```

As you can see clock rate in input stream is 1/90000 (tbn 90k) , but in output 1/1000(tbn 1k).

How can I set a clock rate to 90k in output stream?
Thanks a lot for help

**EDIT**
I accept answer, because it is fact. But I solved my problem replacing webm container in -f parameter with rtp - and clock rate is 90k (tbn)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Matroska and WebM files support a fixed timescale of 1000.